# How to set custom FPS in Java 3D

Tags: java

I want to limit my programs to to certain FPS, otherwise it will run faster in one computer and maybe slower in the other.

I want something like in pygame I do -
FPSClock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPSClock.tick(30)

Is there something like this in Java 3D?
I am a total beginner in Java 3D and I tried to write a Pong games so as to improve my skills. However, I am stuck and realized that there is no way of a proper delay in java because you will not have any idea of what was the last frame's time taken.

I also discovered that KeyEvent is not working in my code.
My code so far -

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import javax.vecmath.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
public class Pong implements KeyListener {
    static float ballx = 0.0f;
    static float bally = 0.0f;
    static float ballz = 0.0f;
    static Transform3D transform2 = new Transform3D();
    static TransformGroup transformGroup2 = new TransformGroup();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
        BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
        Appearance appearance = new Appearance();
        Color3f color = new Color3f(0.1f, 1.8f, 0.1f);
        ColoringAttributes coloringAttributes = new ColoringAttributes(color, ColoringAttributes.NICEST);
        appearance.setColoringAttributes(coloringAttributes);
        Box box = new Box(0.05f, 0.2f, 0.03f, appearance);
        Transform3D transform = new Transform3D();
        TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        transformGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Vector3f vector = new Vector3f(-0.9f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        transform.setTranslation(vector);
        transformGroup.setTransform(transform);
        transformGroup.addChild(box);
        Box box1 = new Box(0.05f, 0.2f, 0.03f, appearance);
        Transform3D transform1 = new Transform3D();
        TransformGroup transformGroup1 = new TransformGroup();
        transformGroup1.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Vector3f vector1 = new Vector3f(0.9f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        transform1.setTranslation(vector1);
        transformGroup1.setTransform(transform1);
        transformGroup1.addChild(box1);
        group.addChild(transformGroup);
        Sphere sphere = new Sphere(0.1f);
        group.addChild(transformGroup1);
        Vector3f vector2 = new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        transform2.setTranslation(vector2);
        transformGroup2.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        transformGroup2.setTransform(transform2);
        transformGroup2.addChild(sphere);
        Color3f lightColor = new Color3f(1.8f, 1.9f, 0.1f);
        BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0,0.0,0.0), 100.0);
        Vector3f lightDirection = new Vector3f(4.0f, -7.0f, -12.0f);
        DirectionalLight light = new DirectionalLight(lightColor, lightDirection);
        light.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        transformGroup2.addChild(light);
        group.addChild(transformGroup2);
        Color3f ambientColor = new Color3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        AmbientLight ambientLightNode = new AmbientLight(ambientColor);
        ambientLightNode.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        transformGroup2.addChild(ambientLightNode);
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(group);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyChar() == 'a') {
            ballx = ballx   0.1f;
            transform2.setTranslation(new Vector3f(ballx, bally, ballz));
            transformGroup2.setTransform(transform2);
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {

    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is most certainly not my area of skill, But from doing a little bit of game programming in java before, I believe you must write your own game loop to control the FPS of your game. So to set a custom FPS you'd have to write a game loop.
A article I found very useful is http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0. It explains which loops are bad practice and shows examples of good game loops.

**Edit:**
In response to your problem with your **Key** methods, I believe that you must call those in the game loop so that they can constantly check the state of the keys.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Python, that link helped me a lot, I will update my program with a timer for hitting 60 FPS on every computer. I am still having one more problem, I did implement KeyListener and also the keyPressed(), keyTyped() and keyReleased() methos in my Pong class. It is neither showing any errors nor is it working. I'll appreciate any help towards this problem

Comment: Totally wrong. Java3D render the scene graph in retained mode. There is no explicit rendering loop.  You just describe the scene, and Java3D will run and show it at maximum speed.

Answer (score 1):

Most Java3D applications and examples run in retained mode, i.e., the user has no control over the rendering loop. But you can define the minimum time, in milliseconds, between each draw frame, using View.view.setMinimumFrameCycleTime(time_in_ms);`
This way you can set the maximum FPS your application will run.

```
Canvas3D myCanvas3D = ...
// To have a maximun of 50FPS, divide 1000ms by 50frames
// and you have 20ms for each frame draw.
View view = myCanvas3D.getView();
view.setMinimumFrameCycleTime(20);
```